# org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

При запуске приложения получаю ошибку:

> org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for
>   delayerModule in class
>   com.project.core.hibernate.entities.DBReadFilesEntity

При этом в файле **guavacached.hbm.xml** следующие настройки:

```
<class name="com.project.core.hibernate.entities.DBReadFilesEntity" table="read_files" catalog="newserver" mutable="false">
        <id name="id">
            <column name="id" sql-type="int unsigned" not-null="true"/>
        </id>
        ...
        <property name="delayerModulesId">
            <column name="delayer_modules_id" sql-type="int unsigned" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="delayerParams">
            <column name="delayer_params" sql-type="varchar" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        ...
        <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" name="delayerModule"
                     class="com.project.core.hibernate.entities.DBModulesEntity">
            <column name="delayer_modules_id" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>
        ...
</class>
```

И вот сам класс **DBReadFilesEntity**:

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "newserver", name = "read_files")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(mutable = false)
public class DBReadFilesEntity {
    private int id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    ...

    private int delayerModulesId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "delayer_modules_id")
    public int getDelayerModulesId() {
        return delayerModulesId;
    }

    public void setDelayerModulesId(int delayerModulesId) {
        this.delayerModulesId = delayerModulesId;
    }

    private String delayerParams;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "delayer_params")
    public String getDelayerParams() {
        return delayerParams;
    }

    public void setDelayerParams(String delayerParams) {
        this.delayerParams = delayerParams;
    }

    ...
}
```

И схема таблицы **read_files**:

```
CREATE TABLE `read_files` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...,
  `delayer_modules_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '4001',
  `delayer_params` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  ...,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ...,
  KEY `FK_read_files_delayer_id` (`delayer__modules_id`),
  ...,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_read_files_delayer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`delayer_modules_id`) REFERENCES `modules` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ...
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251
```

В чём заключается ошибка?

Comment: `<many-to-one name="delayerModule"  ... ` видимо неправильно сделана связь многие к одному.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странный у вас маппинг, у вас есть поле **delayerModulesId**, но при этом у вас есть поле **delayerModule** связаное с **delayer_modules_id** (собственно хайбер и ругается, что его нет в классе).

Если вы хотели указать связь именно поля **delayerModulesId** с **id** в другой таблице, то нужно подправить так:

Это убрать:

```
<property name="delayerModulesId">
   <column name="delayer_modules_id" sql-type="int unsigned" not-null="true"/>
</property>
```

А это исправить:

```
    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" name="delayerModulesId"
                 class="com.project.core.hibernate.entities.DBModulesEntity">
        <column name="delayer_modules_id" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
```

Также при связях в классе вместо этого поля будет храниться объект класса той таблицы, на которую он ссылается:

```
private DBModulesEntity delayerModulesId;
```

**P.S.** А если честно, то вам нужно ИЛИ использовать xml маппинг или аннотации. Оба способа применять не нужно. (А в новых версиях xml маппинг вроде бы вабще исключили)

**P.S.S.** Вы в маппинге можете в принципе не указывать наличие связей, если вам не нужны явные ссылки на связанный объект.